# how to run simple minikube inside docker?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I'm trying to follow instructions on this [guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/) but under docker.

I set up a folder with:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
└── main.py
0 directories, 2 files
```

`main.py` is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

print("Docker is magic!")
```

Dockerfile is:

```
FROM python:latest
COPY main.py /
CMD [ "python", "./main.py" ]

FROM python:3.7-alpine
COPY ./ /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN apk add curl openssl bash --no-cache
RUN curl -LO "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl" \
    && chmod +x ./kubectl \
    && mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl


kubectl create deployment hello-node --image=k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4

kubectl expose deployment hello-node --type=LoadBalancer --port=38080

minikube start --driver=docker

kubectl get pods
```

When I run docker run python-test I see in terminal:

```
Docker is magic!
```

but I don't see the get pods output.

My goal here is to run a simple `minikube` in the docker that just print the list of the pods. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use kubernetes inside a docker container my suggestion is to use k3d .

> k3d is a lightweight wrapper to run k3s (Rancher Lab’s minimal Kubernetes distribution) in docker.k3d makes it very easy to create single- and multi-node k3s clusters in docker, e.g. for local development on Kubernetes.

You can Download , install and use it directly with Docker.
For more information you can follow the official documentation from https://k3d.io/ .

To get the list of pods you dont' need to create a k8s cluster inside a docker container .
what you need is a config file for any k8s cluster
.
├── Dockerfile
├-- config
└── main.py
0 directories, 3 files

after that :

```
FROM python:latest
COPY main.py /
CMD [ "python", "./main.py" ]

FROM python:3.7-alpine
COPY ./ /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN apk add curl openssl bash --no-cache
RUN curl -LO "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl" \
    && chmod +x ./kubectl \
    && mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl

COPY config ~/.kube/config
# now if you execute k get pods you can get the list of pods
#Example;
RUN kubectl get pods
```

to get this file config you can follow this link [Organizing Cluster Access Using kubeconfig Files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/)

I hope that can help you to resolve your issue .

Comment: thanks but I'm not sure I understand how to use it. Can you please show example how to launch it in a simple docker like I use in the question?

Comment: I understand what you want , to get the list of pods from  a cluster you need only the kubernetes config file and kubectl after that you can run it inside a container and get the list of pods , I'll update my response  on details

Comment: investing but where is the k3s commands here? Don't I need to start the cluster with k3s first? this is what I'm missing. I'm launching an empty docker I want to create a small k8s env inside of it. nothing exists when I start it...

Comment: be sure that you copy the right kubeconfig file , for example I'm now connected to a specific cluster and working correctly , I just copy this file and make a Dockerfile on top of it and it's working fine because , what kubectl need is the kubeconfig file only after that he can access to you k8s cluster .

Comment: but this is the issue I don't want to connect to existing cluster I want this to be used for unit testing to run locally so I want every time the docker is running to start a small pod and just running a dummy thing. so for example I want the docker to start a clsuter, create a pod and just print the list of pods and terminate the cluster

Comment: hello slava , for your case you should using kind kubernetes, kind is a tool for running local Kubernetes clusters using Docker container “nodes”.
kind was primarily designed for testing Kubernetes itself, but may be used for local development or CI.  https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/

Comment: so we are back to the same question. How do I set it up. the tutorials do not explain this. I'm just looking for the 4 commands to write in the docker file. In that case.. install kind, create cluster, print kubectl cluster-info.

Comment: Clear, you have right so to resolve your issue you should follow this example : https://github.com/bharatmicrosystems/kind-nginx